# Change url encode entities into html characters?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I used the jquery function `serialize()` for a form, made an ajax call, and use php to do the form processing.

I have a textarea in that form where users type uses spaces and line breaks. I can access the values with $_POST, but its doesnt interpret the line breaks into html `<br/ >` tags. Is there a function that converts line breaks the urlencoded string into `<br/>` tags and other html tags? Or is everything already decoded by the time i access it with $_POST that i cant do anything with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nl2br($text);` (new-line to break-rule)

Comment: Well, what i can i say. Problem SOLVED WOOHOOO THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using [nl2br()](http://php.net/nl2br) while echoing textarea's value ?

edit: too late:P

Comment: Its fine Thanks so much =D. Didnt know that function!

Answer (score 1):

in PHP you have a function to add `<br>` before any new line : [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

You should use it only when you print the text in the textarea with echo, not for storing in your Database.

You also can find a use of [addslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) to avoid any problems with the caracteres `'` and `"` in your textarea

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't want to apply html tags into the value, you can later display the line spacing correctly by applying the CSS `white-space` property into the element where the text appears, and setting it to `pre` or something similar. For more information check out the documentation on it on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_white-space.asp).

Comment: There are [several](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) [better](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/white-space/) [sites](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html) for HTML and CSS reference. w3schools is notoriously dubious.

Comment: MDN is usually very thorough.